# Connection between the two definitions of Siegel Upper Half Space

Tags: several-complex-variables, siegel-modular-forms

It seems, there are two definitions of the Siegel upper half space.

1) One used by, say, Krantz in "Explorations in Harmonic Analysis; Page 252, or, by So Chin Chew and Mei Chi Shaw in "Partial Differential Equations in Several Variables": Page 171:

$\mathbb{H}_{n}=\left\{ \left(z_{1},z_{2},\cdots,z_{n}\right)\in\mathbb{C}^{n}\mid\mathrm{im}(z_{1})>\sum_{j=2}^{n}|z_{j}|^{2}\right\} $

2) And,the other used more classically in most literature concerning Siegel Modular forms:

$\mathbb{H}_{g}=\left\{ Z=X+iY\in\mathrm{M_{g}(\mathbb{C})\mid Z}\mbox{ is symmetric and }Y\mbox{ is positive definite}\right\} $

Are these two definitions equivalent, via say, some biholomorphic map connecting the two for $n=\frac{g(g+1)}{2}$?

Comment: It's hard to see how they could be, given that the first is $n$-dimensional and the second is $n(n+1)/2$-dimensional

Comment: Sorry, I have now edited the question. I implied that when they are of same dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are two different "classical domains". An on-line discussion of the four families of classical domains, related semi-simple real Lie groups, and some related matters is at http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/lie/ in the note "classical groups, domains, cones".

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the first definition is of the Siegel domain of the second kind. The Siegel upper half plane is a Siegel domain of the *first* kind (this terminology was introduced by Piatetsky-Shapiro, see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel_domain) and references therein.